# Timer implementation

Tags: java, time, timer

How can you implement some kind of timer, to know how much time did user spend for one round of a game?

Comment: What context? Is this a Swing GUI program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting [System.currentTimeMillis](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) will get your system time to the millisecond. If you want to do a Swing event intermittently, such as displaying the current time in a stop watch or a simple animation, then a [Swing Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would work well.

Answer (score 0):

One can easily find the time spent by a user on one round of a game by using System.nanoTime() function. However if you want to implement in a game, you would probably like the timer to also be displayed to the user, you can you use multi-threading for the same.

Comment: Nanoseconds are not only unnecessarily granular, but they are typically inaccurate. Especially when you consider the numerous levels of abstraction between the program being written and the actual clock.